# how to do to make sure phonegap js load just once time in an app with many separate pages?

Tags: performance, cordova

Use phonegap 1.6,now called cordova 1.6, with jquery mobile 1.0.1,but I feel performance is a problem.
Also with some other js libs,such as iscroll.js, plus the performance problem.

Can I load phonegap js just once,and later all pages can still use phonegap api?

I have an idea that Page A load phonegap js ,and nested iframe refer Page B.
Page B will replace by other pages. Can Pages in iframe use its parent phonegap api?

eg: parent.(all phonegap api)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Mobile data-role="page" to define multiple pages on a single html page with one phonegap.js load.

See the docs at http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html

Comment: is a oa project,and there are many interactions between client with server. I think it maybe not an good idea to define multiple pages on a single html page.